# How to say »there must be something wrong with you« in German?

Tags: english-to-german

I got a translation in the German version of 'Friends' (TV series):

> Irgendwas muss daran mit dir faul sein.

Is it a correct translation? Do we have better ones? I couldn't find this usage of 'faul' in dictionary via Google. To me 'faul' only means 'lazy'.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to clarify: 1) What is the original line? 2) What is the context of the original line? 3) What do you already know and why are you skeptical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

> Irgendetwas stimmt nicht mit dir.

The translation that you provided is not entirely correct (in terms of grammar). "irgendwas muss faul sein" is more used when a situation seems to be a bit strange, it is not commonly used for people.